# Trying to display multiple input values by clicking multiple buttons on same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

My aim is to leave a comment under each blog post on a page. However, I am struggling to get *all* buttons and input fields into JS and get the input values to display on the page.

Here is my JS code: I'm trying to loop through each button and get the corresponding input value. I've also tried `let text = document.previousSibling.value;` I'm quite new to coding so feel a bit lost as to what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

```
let postArr = document.querySelectorAll('#post');
let inputBox = document.querySelectorAll('#commentBox').values;

function updateComments(){
   postArr.forEach(function(btn){
       btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
           let li = document.createElement("li");
           let text = document.createTextNode(inputBox[i]);
           li.appendChild(text);
           document.getElementById("unordered").appendChild(li);
     
        });
   })

}
```

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<section class="article">
    <h3>BLOG POST #1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam reiciendis eius veritatis possimus magni esse, ipsum vel consectetur,
        alias tenetur quis. Assumenda saepe aperiam vero cupiditate iusto perspiciatis provident. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Placeat perspiciatis quis ipsam sunt voluptates suscipit, alias omnis in possimus libero quam quos. Quidem unde eum accusamus eos eligendi, possimus ratione.</p>
        <section class="commentList">
            <ul id="unordered">
           
            </ul>
        </section>
        
        <section class="comment">
            <label>LEAVE A COMMENT</label>
            <input type="text" id="commentBox" placeholder="Enter comment">
            <button id="post" onclick="updateComments()">POST</button>
            <button class="like" onclick="updateLike()">LIKE</button>
        </section>
        <button class="save">SAVE FOR LATER</button>
    </section>

<section class="article">
    <h3>BLOG POST #2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam reiciendis eius veritatis possimus magni esse, ipsum vel consectetur,
        alias tenetur quis. Assumenda saepe aperiam vero cupiditate iusto perspiciatis provident. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Placeat perspiciatis quis ipsam sunt voluptates suscipit, alias omnis in possimus libero quam quos. Quidem unde eum accusamus eos eligendi, possimus ratione.</p>
    <section class="commentList">
        <ul id="unordered">
       
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="comment">
        <label>LEAVE A COMMENT</label>
        <input type="text" id="commentBox" placeholder="Enter comment">
        <button onclick = "updateComments()" id="post">POST</button>
        <button onclick= "updateLike()" class="like">LIKE</button>
    </section>
    <button class="save">SAVE FOR LATER</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Hello! Can you also post your html markup?

Comment: Hey, sure! just did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there: on click you need to get the value and append the comment, so there is no need to set extra click listeners or select all elements, instead, pass the reference to that button to the function which will do the rest, and then you could use `previousSibling`, since you don't have unique IDs or other reference.

So, that's not the best way to do it, you should rearrange HTML, to either try to have unique IDs and pass it to the function, so that instead of using `previousElementSibling` etc. you could then use `querySelector`

Try this:

```js
    function updateComments(btn) {

        console.log('updateComments, button: ', btn, 'input value: ', btn.previousElementSibling.value, 'list: ', btn.parentElement.previousElementSibling)

        // get UL element..
        const list = btn.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild;

        let li = document.createElement("li");
        let text = document.createTextNode(btn.previousElementSibling.value);
        li.appendChild(text);
        list.appendChild(li);

        // reset input
        btn.previousElementSibling.value = '';
    }
```

```html
<section class="article">
        <h3>BLOG POST #1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam reiciendis eius veritatis possimus magni esse, ipsum vel consectetur, alias tenetur quis. Assumenda saepe aperiam vero cupiditate iusto perspiciatis provident. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat perspiciatis quis ipsam sunt voluptates suscipit, alias omnis in possimus libero quam quos. Quidem unde eum accusamus eos eligendi, possimus ratione.</p>
        <section class="commentList">
            <ul id="unordered">
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="comment">
            <label>LEAVE A COMMENT</label>
            <input type="text" id="commentBox" placeholder="Enter comment">
            <button id="post" onclick="updateComments(this)">POST</button>
            <button class="like" onclick="updateLike()">LIKE</button>
        </section>
        <button class="save">SAVE FOR LATER</button>
    </section>
    <section class="article">
        <h3>BLOG POST #2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam reiciendis eius veritatis possimus magni esse, ipsum vel consectetur, alias tenetur quis. Assumenda saepe aperiam vero cupiditate iusto perspiciatis provident. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat perspiciatis quis ipsam sunt voluptates suscipit, alias omnis in possimus libero quam quos. Quidem unde eum accusamus eos eligendi, possimus ratione.</p>
        <section class="commentList">
            <ul id="unordered">
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="comment">
            <label>LEAVE A COMMENT</label>
            <input type="text" id="commentBox" placeholder="Enter comment">
            <button onclick="updateComments(this)" id="post">POST</button>
            <button onclick="updateLike()" class="like">LIKE</button>
        </section>
        <button class="save">SAVE FOR LATER</button>
    </section>
```